# 0.00 should not be the answer

Tags: java, object, methods

```
package CompanyEmployees;

public class DoEmployeePayroll {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        FullTimeEmployee ftEmployee = new FullTimeEmployee();

        ftEmployee.setName("Barry Burd");
        ftEmployee.setJobTitle("CEO");
        ftEmployee.setWeeklySalary(5000.00);
        ftEmployee.setBenefitDeduction(500.00);
        ftEmployee.cutCheck(ftEmployee.findPaymentAmount());
        System.out.println();

        PartTimeEmployee ptEmployee = new PartTimeEmployee();

        ptEmployee.setName("Steve Surace");
        ptEmployee.setJobTitle("Driver");
        ptEmployee.setHourlyRate(7.53);
        ptEmployee.cutCheck(ptEmployee.findPaymentAmount(10));
    }
}

package CompanyEmployees;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Employee {

    private String name;
    private String jobTitle;

    public void setName(String nameIn) {
        name = nameIn;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setJobTitle(String jobTitleIn) {
        jobTitle = jobTitleIn;
    }

    public String getJobTitle() {
        return jobTitle;
    }

    public void cutCheck(double amountPaid) {
        out.printf("Pay to the order of %s ", name);
        out.printf("(%s) ***$", jobTitle);
        out.printf("%,.2f\n", amountPaid);
    }
}


package CompanyEmployees;

public class PartTimeEmployee extends Employee {

    private double hourlyRate;

    public void setHourlyRate(double rateIn) {
        rateIn = hourlyRate;
    }

    public double getHourlyRate() {
        return hourlyRate;
    }

    public double findPaymentAmount(int hours) {
        return hourlyRate * hours;
    }
}
```

I calculated the Full Time Employee but it's the Part Time that won't come out right. The payment should be 75.30 but it outputs 0.00.

Comment: Relook at setHourlyRate

Comment: And don't use floating-point for anything that needs to be exact.

Answer (score 1):

You've reversed the arguments here

```
private double hourlyRate;
public void setHourlyRate(double rateIn) {
  rateIn = hourlyRate;
}
```

Should be

```
public void setHourlyRate(double rateIn) {
  this.hourlyRate = rateIn;
}
```